# design select option with two differnt languages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a select box in html and my select options text contain two different languages
I want to give to each language a different font family because the font families not support both languages
my code now looks like that:

```html
<select name="" class="" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="בדיקה test">בדיקה <span class="en">test</span></option>
    <option value="בדיקה test">בדיקה <span class="en">test</span></option>
    <option value="בדיקה test">בדיקה <span class="en">test</span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want the 'test' text to be a different font?

Comment: exactly that what i want

Comment: Give it a class and set the font in the class?

Comment: it has a class - en
but the style not work on it

Comment: Ah - the `options` (are meant to) have different fonts - `option` elements have very limited options for styling and you can't nest html inside an `option`.  Try something like [tag:select2]